# want to show a image when enter a particular region of lat. long by zoom in and out android

Tags: android

hi friends i am able to display Google map in my android device and by default i am able to perform zoom in and out,so  now i want to show a image when i enter,A REGION of between lat. long then a small pop msg appear at top of google map as "you enter buenos region"(Buenos is just place name whose coordinate area i take),so now how to show it in android,i have consult with iphone developer who develop same concept using the code below,but i am not understanding how to implement for zoomin and out for getting lat. long. of particular region..pls take  a look below...

```
   if((centerCoordinate.latitude < -34.538238) && (centerCoordinate.latitude > -34.672182))
   {
      if((centerCoordinate.longitude < -58.347702) && (centerCoordinate.longitude > -58.528976))
  {
  img_City.hidden = NO;
 }
 else 
     {
  img_City.hidden  = YES;
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom, you need to get map the coordinates on the screen corners, you can do that by using

[`fromPixels()`](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Projection.html#fromPixels%28int,%20int%29)

Once you get this, all you have to do is check if the bounds like between the region bounds, like you did in the code in your question. The only difference is that instead of the center coordinates, you are using the rect formed by your screen as 4 coordinates.

If the bound checking works out, add an `Overlay` to the `MapView`.

Comment: Frankly it is too much to explain from scratch. First start with this [tutorial](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android), to learn how to add an Image using Overlays. AFter completing it you will understand what my answer says